# Prediction based on multiple time series - Python

Tags: regression, time-series, multiple-regression, python

I have 3 predictors and 1 variable that represents ground truth. They all are linked time series. My purpose is with the 3 predictors to try to forecast the ground truth data.

For example :

```
list1        = 15,224,32,14,55,67 
list2        = 21,331,42,41,31,43
list3        = 43,423,12,65,42,53
ground truth = 55,500,34,12,? ,?
```

I want to predict the ground truth new values depending on past values of list1, list2, list3.

I looked this example but actually, I cannot understand how can i fit it for my problem.
http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/predict.html

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it essential that an answer make reference to Python?

Comment: Independent of whether python or not, there is still the question about what the right model for the prediction is. The standard answer, I assume, would be to use something like VAR (vector autoregression) if only lagged values enter the prediction. However, the example data are too short for any time series approach, and the 500 value looks like a big outlier as a time series. It would be much easier to predict if the same period explanatory variables could be used.

Comment: How long are your time series? Besides VAR being a natural candidate, I am wondering if any black box could do (neural network, random forest and the like). Also, your saying *It would be much easier to predict if the same period explanatory variables could be used* is just an unrealistic wish or are you allowed to do that in principle?